# How to color certain entries of a matrix?

Tags: colors

I am a beginner in MATLAB. I want to color some of my results, but don't know what command to use: For instance, if given a matrix, say A = [1 2;2 3]; How can I change the 2 in the first row and the second column to red?

Thanks in advance for your help!

I've tried using cprintf, but have no clue how to put things like A(1,2) in it.